# PySimpleGUI need to add a check for event == WIN_CLOSED error

Tags: python, pysimplegui

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import math

layout = [
    [sg.Text('Calculator', font=('Helvetica', 20))],
    [sg.Text('', size=(10,1), font=('Helvetica', 20), key='result')],
    [sg.Button('7', size=(5,2)), sg.Button('8', size=(5,2)), sg.Button('9', size=(5,2)), sg.Button('+', size=(5,2))],
    [sg.Button('4', size=(5,2)), sg.Button('5', size=(5,2)), sg.Button('6', size=(5,2)), sg.Button('-', size=(5,2))],
    [sg.Button('1', size=(5,2)), sg.Button('2', size=(5,2)), sg.Button('3', size=(5,2)), sg.Button('*', size=(5,2))],
    [sg.Button('0', size=(5,2)), sg.Button('.', size=(5,2)), sg.Button('=', size=(5,2)), sg.Button('/', size=(5,2))],
    [sg.Button('sin', size=(5,2)), sg.Button('cos', size=(5,2)), sg.Button('tan', size=(5,2)), sg.Button('sqrt', size=(5,2))],
    [sg.Button('log', size=(5,2)), sg.Button('Clear', size=(5,2))]
]

window = sg.Window('Calculator', layout)

result = ''

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in (None, 'Clear'): 
        result = ''
    elif event in ('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '.', '+', '-', '*', '/', 'log'):
        result += event
    elif event == '=':
        try:
            result = eval(result)
            result = str(result)
        except Exception as e:
            result = f'Error: {e}'
    elif event == 'sin': 
        try:
            result = math.sin(float(result))
            result = str(result)
        except Exception as e:
            result = f'Error: {e}'
    elif event == 'cos':
        try:
            result = math.cos(float(result))
            result = str(result)
        except Exception as e:
            result = f'Error: {e}'
    elif event == 'tan':
        try:
            result = math.tan(float(result))
            result = str(result)
        except Exception as e:
            result = f'Error: {e}'
    elif event == 'sqrt':
        try:
            result = math.sqrt(float(result))
            result = str(result)
        except Exception as e:
            result = f'Error: {e}'
    elif event == sg.WIN_CLOSED :
        break

window.close()
```

i have here a simple calculator app, which is able to run but the buttons don't work and when i try to close the app a following error popup appears : ERROR Trying to read a closed window, line 20, in event, values = window.read(), You have tried 100 times to read a closed window., You need to add a check for event == WIN_CLOSED

this made me confused because i've already added

```
elif event == sg.WIN_CLOSED :
        break
```

any ideas to help point me in the right direction? i'm a beginner.

tried re-writing the sg.WIN_CLOSED command. still doesn't work.

Comment: Instead of "while True:" please use: "while not window.was_closed():"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get an event `sg.WIN_CLOSED` which is `None` when you click `X` button of the window, window already destroyed before you got the event and you cannot call `window.read()` again, should break from `while` loop. That's why you got exception `Trying to read a closed window`

Should not combine the check for `None` and `'Clear'` together.

```py
    if event in (None, 'Clear'): 
        result = ''
```

It should be

```py
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == 'Clear': 
        result = ''
```

Comment: solved. thank you so much. could you also help me with the button not showing output problem as well?

Comment: Add `window['result'].update(result)` as the last statement in the `while` loop. Of course, there is still issue in the script, like new number add after a `=` calculation, or the `Input` element for the result will be better, try to use `expand_x` to get maximum width of a element in the parent.